# Calling async web service using Xcode

Tags: xcode, multithreading, web, asynchronous, service

I'm planning on using a web service call from Xcode and need it to be performant. Do I call the service from a background thread and then update the UI on another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for your purposes (written in **Swift**):

```
// Go to an asynchronous thread
// .userInitiated quality of service for a high-priority task
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
  // Make sure you have a reference to self if you need it here
  guard let self = self else {
    return
  }

  // Make your asynchronous web service call here

  // Now return to the main thread
  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    // Make sure you have a reference to self if you need it here
    guard let self = self else {
      return
    }

    // Update your UI here
  }
}
```

For more on `DispatchQueue` and the different qualities of service, I recommend this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I don't need to move my async call to a location away from the UI code or embed it in a class or method declared as Async?

Comment: Right, the method doesn't need to be declared as asynchronous. You should be able to just wrap the code you want to execute on a background thread in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async` and then `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you want to return to the main thread